# how to tag part of a sentence (more than one word) with nltk taggers

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I am playing around with the nltk taggers and built a tagger hierarchy based on two german sentences:

```
traindata = [
    [('ich bin dabei', 'PV')],
    [('ich', 'test'), ('bin', 'None'), ('nicht', 'NV'), ('dabei', 'None')],
]

t0 = nltk.DefaultTagger('None')
t1 = nltk.UnigramTagger(traindata, backoff=t0)
t2 = nltk.BigramTagger(traindata, backoff=t1)
t3 = nltk.TrigramTagger(traindata, backoff=t2)
```

input: `ich bin dabei`

expected: `[('ich bin dabei', 'PV')]`

result: `[('ich', 'test'), ('bin', 'None'), ('dabei', 'None')]`

The word `ich` was tagged based on the second element in traindata, although I expected all three words `ich bin dabei` to be tagged as `PV`.

How can I tag more than one word with nltk taggers? Also same with part of a sentence:

`ich bin dabei, hoffe ich`

should result in

`[('ich bin dabei', 'PV'), ('hoffe', 'None'), ('ich', 'None')]`

Comment: The POS taggers work with tokens, not strings. Unless the input `ich bin dabei` is parsed as a single token, it cannot be processed the way you imagine. You need a chunker, not a POS tagger.

Comment: you mean I need a solution to first recognize `ich bin dabei` as one chunk, right? After that I can tag that chunk?

Comment: No. Even chunks are recognized one token at a time. You need to change your approach, and for this you need to understand that the nltk works with sequences of tokens. What is `PV` anyway, and how much training data of this sort do you have? Your question cannot be answered as it stands now.

Comment: PV, NV, test.... these are not real tags. Training data is not more than you see there. The question was written to understand tagging sentences and taggers and in hope to get a better approach to achieve my goal. I hope I could make clear what the goal is. I only want to tag sentences. We can assume that I have cool tags and tons of training data of this sort.

Comment: To understand tagging, read chapter 5 of the NLTK book. For chunking, read chapters 6 and 7. I'm not sure what you expect from an answer here, since you have no clear task to be carried out or problem to be solved.

Comment: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't present a solvable, practical problem and thus is impossible to be given a distinct answer."
Shucks, cannot vote to close because of the bounty. So, -1 instead.